# How can I lock a specific application in Ubuntu 20.10?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, ubuntu-gnome, 20.10

I'm using Ubuntu 20.10 (Wayland) and I'm looking for an app locker. I search google but nothing good came up. Tell me if you know any good app locker like "Smart-X AppLocker for windows".